# Why is replaced text erasure inconsistent?

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote a simple sequence to output, when typing somewhere the string `mdcode`, a Markdown code block template such as

````
```python

```
````

The code to create the above works most of the time:

```
::mdcode::
{
  ; query user for the language of the code block
  Lang := InputBox(,  "input MD code language")
  ; send the code block structure
  Send "{U+0060}{U+0060}{U+0060}" . Lang.Value . "`n`n`n{U+0060}{U+0060}{U+0060}{Up}"
}
```

Sometimes (this is hardly reproducible), some of the letters of `mdcode` are not erased during the execution of the code and I end up with `mdcode` not entirely removed

````
mdc```python

```
````

(the number of letters remaining varies, it can be one, it can be three, ...)

I guess that there is some kind of timing issue where the building of the code block is started before the replacement of `mdcode` is done. Is this something fixable?

Comment: In which environment are you working?

Comment: @harrymc: Windows 10. This behaviour is with all kinds of editors (notepad, vscode, web-based textareas)

Comment: Try SendInput instead of Send.

Answer (score 0):

This is because InputBox GUI, add `Sleep 100` line after, so input window will have time to switch focus back to itself.